# Virtualbox conflicting with getting ip

Tags: java, connection, ip

I'm having trouble returning the correct IP, after i installed oracle's virtualbox. It prints me following:

```
VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter 192.168.56.1
VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter fe30:0:0:0:1323:fahd:bt75:8422%eth1
Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter 2041:0:91q8:6at8:30he:3r2c:3a53:ff4c
Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter fj80:0:0:0:32bn:1e2z:3f37:ff5c%net4
Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller 192.168.0.163
Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller fe30:0:0:0:3a4c:bf90:232a:a324%eth6
```

I only want to return 192.168.0.163

I used this code to get the IP:

```
String ip;
            try {
                Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
                while (interfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
                    NetworkInterface iface = interfaces.nextElement();
                    // filters out 127.0.0.1 and inactive interfaces
                    if (iface.isLoopback() || !iface.isUp())
                        continue;

                    Enumeration<InetAddress> addresses = iface.getInetAddresses();
                    while(addresses.hasMoreElements()) {
                        InetAddress addr = addresses.nextElement();
                        ip = addr.getHostAddress();
                        System.out.println(iface.getDisplayName() + " " + ip);
                    }
                }
            } catch (SocketException es) {
                throw new RuntimeException(es);
            }
```

How do i retrieve only the wanted IP?

Comment: *Why* are you collecting all the IPs addresses of your computer?

Comment: @Andreas i need to establish a connection to a device, which needs a call from the pc to get the IP. And yes i need this in a java application.

Comment: Why do you need you *own* address to connect to a device? Wouldn't you need the address of the *device*? If you have that, let the system use the routing tables to make the connection. Then I believe you can always ask the connection what the address is, but not knowing what *kind* of connection you're establishing, I can't be sure.

Comment: @Andreas The connection is made from the clientside which is the android app. It needs to know what IP it needs to do the socket connection.

Comment: In that case use a Broadcast Packet to announce your presence on the network, then have the server respond to that Packet so the client knows the server IP

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond I tried that, and miserably failed :(

Comment: @AndersLassen So how are you going to tell the device what the address is?

Comment: @Andreas user enters it manually and connects. I couldn't work out how to use the UDP packages to send and detect the server's ip via the android app.

Comment: So show the IPs, with descriptions, and let the user choose.

Comment: @Andreas I would like to know if there is any way to get a list of all IP Addresses that are connected to the same WIFI.
All the IP Addresses that each user is using in the network.
I want to use this because i want to connect an android app and computer program together using sockets, without the user having to specify what IP Address either of the components have.

Comment: @AndersLassen That's a *totally* different question. If you want to know *that*, you should create a new question, and probably not here, but on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To communicate without having an IP, the best way is either through a discovery service or with broadcast UDP packets.

You will need a few things:

1. A server listening for broadcast packets either on a specific port,
   or in general.
2. A client (in this case your android app) that listens on a specific
   port for a connection(TCP/UDP depends on your applications needs).
3. The client will also need to be able to send out a broadcast packet on the   network identifying itself.

Basically the steps go as follows:

1. Server binds ports needed for UDP broadcast receipt.
2. Client binds port to receive response from server (lets say port 16000 for example)
3. The Client then sends the broadcast packet on the network which is sent to all clients.
4. The server receives the packet and with the packets info gets the IP address of the client.
5. The server then responds to the client via the listening port (in this case 16000) either via UDP or TCP.
6. Once the connection to the client is established the client knows via the connection information the IP of the server, has an active connection to it, and can potentially save the address for later.

The technical details can be found all over stackoverflow, but it varies depending on the programming languages of the server/client and the operating systems involved.

Here is a tutorial via Oracle Documentation for Java:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html

One for C#:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tst0kwb1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is very nice, thank you!
However, as far i as understood from some other topics - when testing the UDP discovery with an emulator there's some sort of problem with the network between the emulator and the computer i run the emulator on. I'm not sure if you know what im talking about?

Comment: You will probably have to do some port forwarding in that case if it is on an emulator.

Comment: i have no idea how, haha.

Comment: IT WORKS - I fixed the problem! Thank you so much for your help, struggled for so long haha :D